If $F(\alpha) = F(\alpha^2)$, then $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$
Let $K$ be an extension of a field $F$ and let $\alpha \in K$. If $F(\alpha) = F(\alpha^2)$, then $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$.
 I have an idea about how to do this that doesn't trivialize the problem in the sense that simple (hence, finite) extensions are algebraic already.  $\color{red}{\leftarrow \mathrm{Simple \,\, extensions \,\, need  \, \, not \, \, be \, \, finite. }}$
Now, $[F(\alpha):F] = n = [F(\alpha^2):F]$. Hence, we have that the sets
$$\{1, \alpha, \dots, \alpha^n\} \hspace{1cm} \{1, \alpha^2, \dots, \alpha^{2n}\}$$
are two distinct linearly dependent subsets of $F(\alpha)$ $($or $F(\alpha^2))$. Then we have $a_0, \dots, a_n$ not all $0$ so that
$$a_0+a_1\alpha+ \dots +a_n\alpha^n = 0 \tag{1}$$
WLOG, let $a_k$ be the nonzero coefficient. Symmetrically, we have $b_0, \dots, b_n$ not all $0$ so that
$$b_0 + b_1 \alpha^2 + \dots +\beta_n\alpha^{2n}=0 \tag{2}$$
Let $b_l$ be the nonzero coefficient. Now, adding $(1)+(2)$, we get another equation
$$(a_0+b_0) + a_1\alpha+ (a_2 +b_1)\alpha^2 + \dots + (a_j+b_{j/2})\alpha^j + \dots + b_n\alpha^{2n}=0$$
As $a_k$ and $b_l$ from before are non-zero then as long as all of the coefficients in $(3)$ are not $a_k+b_l$ and as long as $a_k \neq - b_l$, then there is a polynomial $p(x)$ based on $(3)$ for which $p(\alpha)=0$.
How can I ensure that $a_k + b_l$ is not a coefficient and that $a_k \neq - b_l$?
EDIT: I made the silly mistake of assuming that simple extensions need to be of finite degree. But this is not the case if $\alpha$ is transcendental.

How can you assume that the extension degree is finite? This is actually what you have to prove.

Finite extensions are always algebraic, so by assuming that you are solving only the trivial case. Now you need to solve the interesting case.

If $\alpha \in F(\alpha^2)$, that says there are polynomials $P$ and $Q$ over $F$, $Q \ne 0$, such that
$\alpha = P(\alpha^2)/Q(\alpha^2)$, i.e. $\alpha$ is a root of the polynomial $x Q(x^2) - P(x^2)$.

And this polynomial is $\not=0$ since the degree of the first term is odd and that of the second one is even.
